# Black Screen is showing for a while when screen orientation is changing

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

I am using one listview and one dynamic listview in the same xml but the problem I am facing is while changing the orientation in nexus 7 the screen is going black screen for a while and adjusting all the view in this time and In manifest file I specified screensize,orientation,keyboard-hidden for config attribute at activity attribute.I am handling required orientation changes in onConfigurationChanged() but still the black screen is showing for a while.Can you suggest me where I need to make the changes to work in properly
As the code length of code extends no of lines I am sharing my code with below link

Thanks in adavanc
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dCIxgqX0vZIEbWfxWpLNkEDpu_-vd7HDfcGlYSInbHc/

Comment: Are you doing a lot of stuff in your onCreate() method?

Comment: Yes I am loading data for listview and dynamic view and for listview is adjusting dynamic view is taking some time for adjusting.

Comment: Post code - we can't help unless we see what your `Activity` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a lot things in onCreate() and onResume(). any file operation and network operation should go to asynctask. the only thing you should do is manipulate UI. see http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: I am calling asynctask in on create method so I  am not putting any pressure on main ui thread.